# React Native Geolocation Timed Out

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, geolocation

I use geolocation to get the current location of users in my project. but I get the Timed Out Error error.

***{TIMEOUT: 3, POSITION_UNAVAILABLE: 2, PERMISSION_DENIED: 1, message: "Location request timed out", code: 3}***

API 28 android phone success,
API 21 android phone success,
API 23 android phone time out error.

All permission granted.

```
   try{
            Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                position => {
                    const initialPosition = JSON.stringify(position);

                    this.setState({
                        firstLat: position.coords.latitude,
                        firstLng: position.coords.longitude,
                    });
                    this.getLocation(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                    this.setState({
                        isLoading:true
                    })

                },
                error => console.log(error),
                {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout:10000, maximumAge:1000},
            );


        }catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

thank you.